# How to set calendar availability on a per-day basis in Outlook 2007?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

In Outlook 2007, you can go to "Tools" > "Options" > "Calendar Options" button and set your start and end times for the day.

Is there anyway for me to further limit my calendar, so I can set my **availability on a per-day basis**?

E.G. (my calendar would be available for others to invite me to meetings at these times)

- Mon - 9am - 5pm
- Tues - 7am - 3pm
- Wed - 7am - 3pm
- Thurs - 9am - 5pm
- Fri - 9am - 5pm

I'd like to setup my availability ahead of time, for each of the week, that would be the same going forward.

I realize that I could create an appointment for myself that blocks out those times, but that seems pretty lame. And it fills the 'To-Do Bar' with all the recurrences.

I'm open to suggestions for built-in functionality, or some free utilities/plugins if they exist.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, the only way I know of is to use a category of recurring appointments and just create a custom view that hides them. . .